# Why can't a open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ be compact?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

If I choose $(0,1)$ and do a covering like this:

$(-1,1/2)$ and $(1/3,2)$ it's a finite covering, then $(0,1)$ is a compact set?

Comment: (1) It's not a covering -- 1/2 isn't covered -- and (2) EVERY open covering of the set must contain a finite sub covering.

Comment: sorry it was 1/3,

Comment: for understanding sake, can you give a counterexample?

Comment: *every* open cover must have a finite subcover.  The classic example would be {(1/n, 1 - 1/n)} is an open cover which has no finite subcover.

Comment: @fleablood : Yeah, I posted that below.

Comment: Oops, sorry.  ... well, it *is* the classic counter example.

Comment: So the set of answers is compact, now im so happy I can't chose one.

Comment: Similar questions from the past:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257514/cover-of-0-1-with-no-finite-subcover-open-sets-of-compact-function-spaces
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609217/why-is-an-open-interval-not-a-compact-set
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133580/an-example-of-an-infinite-open-cover-of-the-interval-0-1-that-has-no-finite-su
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245499/proof-of-0-1-is-not-compact-with-usual-metric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(0,1)$ is not compact.

Proof: Consider the open covering $\displaystyle\left\{\left ({1\over n}, 1 - {1\over n}\right) \right\}_{n=3}^\infty$; this is an open covering of $(0,1)$ but it has no finite subcovering.

Answer (score 7):

> If I choose $(0,1)$ and do a covering like this: $(-1,\frac{1}{2})$ and $(\frac{1}{3},2)$ it's a finite covering, then $(0,1)$ is a compact set?

You are misunderstanding the definition of a compact set. The definition starts with "For *every* open coverings, there exists a sub coverings......". So, in order to show that $(0,1)$ is compact, you first have to prove something that is true for *every* open coverings of $(0,1)$, which is quite hard.

The example you gave $(-1,\frac{1}{2})\cup(\frac{1}{3},2)$ is indeed *an* open covering. However, this does not help you much since you will need every possible open coverings.

In fact, to show a set is not compact, all you need is just one counterexample which is already given in other answers. To show a set is compact, however, is much more difficult. Sometimes you can use the definition of compactness directly but as I said, doing something to *every possible open covering* sounds difficult. In these case, people usually either argue by contradiction or use the fact that being closed and bounded *sometimes* implies compactness.

Answer (score 2):

Take the sequence $\large a_n = \frac{1}{n}$, which lives in (0,1).

it converges to a point, $0$, which is *not* in your set (0,1).

and so we say that your set is **not sequentially compact**.

(and so it is not compact.)

Comment: Oh, this is using that fancy theorem about compact iff secuentially compact, thanks a lot!

Comment: yes, and the closedness is essential, not just merely the boundedness, which you already have. I.e., a compact set is **both closed and bounded**.  please feel free to up-vote my answer, if you are happy :)

Comment: how are compactness and sequentially compactness related?

Comment: great question @miracle173 -- in a **metric space** sequential compactness and compactness are equivalent.  This is not true for a general topological space, however.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another argument (which may be useful): we are used to slogan that "in $\mathbb{R}^n$ compact means closed and bounded" (from this you already see that $(0,1)$ not being closed cannot be compact) however compactness is quite different in nature from properties of being bounded and closed:
-being bounded is only with respect to some *metric*: it requires finer structure on our topological space
-closedness is not intrinsic property: the same set may be closed or not, depending on how you embedd it in some ambient space.
This is not the case for compactness!
-compactness does not require metric structure (only topological)
-compactness *is* intrinsic (independent from the embedding).
And why I'm talking about this? Since $(0,1)$ is *topologically* the same as $\mathbb{R}$ so if $(0,1)$ would be compact, so would be $\mathbb{R}$ and for the latter probably you won't have doubts that it is not.